# Creating two different dataframes, one by selecting every nth row and the other one with the remaining data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe 'new' in which I have selected every 10th row and named that as 'x_test1'. Now I want these selected rows (every 10th row) to be deleted from the previously existing dataframe 'new'.
Basically I want two separate dataframes:-

1. with every 10th row, and;
2. other dataframe with the remaining data (excluding the data in dataframe 1)

Here's what I have tried:

```
x_test1 = new.iloc[::10,:] #select every 10th row from 'new' dataframe
dataset = new.drop([x_test1], axis = 0) #returns Value Error
```

Can someone please advise me on this?

Comment: post the sample dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop` by index values:

```
x_test1 = new.iloc[::10]
dataset = new.drop(x_test1.index)
```